# How the IP addresses of all private IP address ranges on a wireless network can be listed?

Tags: ip, ipv4, virtual-wifi, wireless-hotspot

Assume there are two or more different private ip address ranges on a wifi network and my PC is connected to a one ip range.

> As an example there are two address ranges as `192.168.0.*` and `192.168.43.*`. And my PC is connected to the network as `192.168.0.10`.

If I need to find the all the ip addresses connected to the same wifi network disregarding the private IP address range, how can I do it.

> In above mentioned example assume that there are 5 devices are connected to the network as `192.168.0.1`,  `192.168.0.2`, `192.168.43.1`,  `192.168.43.2`, `192.168.43.3` and my PC as  `192.168.0.10`. I want to list all those 6 IP addresses through my PC.

Comment: You can't expect to see traffic not directed to you; switches in the network learns who are where, and only sends traffic to where needed. You need to ping all possible adresses, and hope they answer.
You can ping other ranges than your own, but you don't know if they are physically on the same network than you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a simple discovery tool / IP scanner (Angry IP scanner as example). Just scan all the needed ranges and the IPs will show, assuming a proper routing configuration.

Comment: Yup.  This is pretty much the way to do it, other than using a feature of the Wi-Fi router.  (another approach may be to access the router with HTTPS and see if the router provides a way to report connected devices.  Details about such a feature would vary based on the router being used, as this is not a standardized compatible feature built into common TCP/IP stacks)

Comment: Some home routers have pretty nice functionality that make this job very easy.